# Azure Databricks - Python SSLCertVerificationError - unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: python, ssl, azure-databricks

I have an Azure Databricks notebook that gets a list of CSV files from a public government website and downloads them on a monthly basis or so.  It's automating a process that was manual beforehand.  The automation was working until recently.  This is an SSL error, so it's not some sort of scraping issue.

The failing code is straightforward:

```
import requests
headers = {'Connection': 'Close'}
GovHTML = requests.get(GovURL, headers=headers)
```

It blows up with this (i've slightly obscured things):

> SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='somegovtwebsite.gov', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /PublicReport/default.aspx (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1131)')))

However, when I browse to that URL in a browser and click the cert info, everything looks fine (again, the particular site is obscured):

> Issued to: *.somegovtwebsite.gov
> Issued by: DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1
> Valid from 3/20/2022 to 3/24/2023

Given the dates, it seems likely that the certificate that Databricks is seeing is one that expired roughly at the beginning of the month.  However, the website has a fresh cert that I've shown above.

I have temporarily worked around the issue by changing the request to this:

```
GovHTML = requests.get(GovURL, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

How do I get Databricks/Python to see the new certificate and prevent the issue in the future?  (In a non-crappy way)

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to import a custom ca certificate for the cluster.
By performing this you may not get the error described by you.

To import a ca certificate, you have create a init script which will add the entire CA chain and sets the `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` property .

After that attach the init script to the cluster and then restart the cluster.

Refer the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/python/import-custom-ca-cert) for Indepth explanation and examples

Comment: Explanation is not detailed enough for a normal person to do this